# Why is the golang program panic if adding fmt.Printf?

Tags: go, panic

I have no idea why the program will panic if I add `fmt.Printf("%p\n", sHdr)`, it is OK if not exists. Could someone provide me some clues? Thanks a lot.

```
package main

import (
      "fmt"
      "reflect"
      "unsafe"
)

func main() {
      s := "hello world"

      sHdr := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
      fmt.Println(sHdr.Len)
      fmt.Println(*(*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(sHdr.Data)))

      b := *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(sHdr))
      fmt.Printf("%p\n", sHdr)                  // this line
      fmt.Println(len(b), cap(b))
      fmt.Println(string(b[:len(s)]))
      fmt.Println(b[:len(s)])
  }
```

the output is as follows:

```
11
104
0xc000010200
11 0
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:11] with capacity 0

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /Users/xsky/go/src/github.com/microyahoo/go-exercises/advanced_go/test_string.go:19 +0x3c6
exit status 2
```

If I comment out the line of `fmt.Printf("%p\n", sHdr)`, the program will be OK.

```
11
104
11 824634167072
hello world
[104 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100]
```

Comment: The capacity of  `sHdr` will be 0 after running `fmt.Printf`, why?

Comment: Using `unsafe` is unsafe. In this particular case you've used it to pretend that a string header is a slice header, and a string header *isn't* a slice header—a string header is shorter than a slice header. Things go wrong depending on what's in the memory cells that aren't actually part of the header, but are being used as if they are. Those memory cells get perturbed by function calls.